# Java making a GUI

Tags: java, netbeans

Probably gonna get pooped on for this, I am not asking anybody to do my homework, but I am reaching out for help. I've already done the first question but the professor is asking for me to make a GUI in the second question. I've actually never made a GUI in Java before so this is all really new to me.

2. Make a simple, but visually appealing, GUI that has at least the following features:

a. A text box to enter an email address;

b. A text box to enter a message title;

c. A text area to enter a message;

d. Appropriate labels for text entry areas;

e. Buttons to “Send,” “Save for later,” and “Discard” the message;

f. A checkbox to “Flag as Important.”

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html and other java swing classes.

Comment: so what is it you are asking? you can use AWT (wouldn't recommend it), Swing (wouldn't recommend that either), JavaFX, JSP, JSF, Angular, GWT, ...

Comment: "Probably gonna get pooped on for this" -> if you know your question is not correct why posted it ? " I am not asking anybody to do my homework" -> Then why just post your exercise statement without a trace of research and without a specific question ? Finally if your question is to recommend a way to make GUI this is a wrong question cause answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: @Sean even though Swing is still around, especially for someone learning, and who needs to make a 'visually appealing' GUI, it's not the best option around.

Comment: @Stultuske I understand, I just found that swing was one of the easiest to start with(for me). I've never used some of the other libraries you recommend, only swing and awt, so I really don't know the differences.

Comment: @Sean AWT was basically replaced by Swing, just like Swing has somewhat been replaced by JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

As you marked Netbeans i assume you use this IDE.
To get in touch with gui building i would recommend you the netbeans gui builder:
[Netbeans Gui Builder Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html)

For your simple task this should be more than enough if using such tools for your task is allowed

Comment: The only problems for this approach: you won't understand the code generated, it's pretty hard to update the code with new components without introducing regression bugs, and if your teacher asks you anything about how the components are linked together, you're toast.

Comment: You are absolutly right but for me the task sounds like getting in touch with GUIs as it isn´t further described. With the simple tutorial I have posted this task can easily be completed.

Comment: True, which is why I didn't downvote your answer. Problem with the Netbeans WYSIWYG editor, is, besides the fact that you don't get to see the actual code, unless you dig into it (which no student ever will) you have no idea what happens, and you don't actually learn anything. Also: if you only learn GUI with this editor, and then go to work in a company that doesn't allow the use of Netbeans (yes, they exist), you are in for it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are to just create the controls (text 'box', text area, etc) and not make them do anything, this is really simple to do in Netbeans. just start a new application and drag and drop from the Swing Controls shown on the right of the Netbeans IDE.

For more on building java GUIs, try my guide at
http://philofjava.webstarts.com/

Answer (score -1):

Definitely research on Java applets, that is most likely what the problem is references.
With applets, you can insert all those components onto a pop-up window at the coordinates of your choosing.

Edit: here's a sample from a project I had to do for a project in my java class. It creates the JFrame then puts the components on it. I'd really recommend looking up how to use Swing, a lot of websites offer in depth tutorials for every component you can use.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class aSimpleApplet
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is the frame that holds all the components");
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("A button");
        button.setBounds(25, 25, 150, 50);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField("A text field");
        textField.setBounds(200, 25, 575, 100);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("A text area");

        JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollBar.setBounds(50, 175, 350, 300);

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("A checkbox");
        checkBox.setBounds(400, 200, 250, 50);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("A label");
        label.setBounds(100, 600, 150, 50);

        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.add(scrollBar);
        frame.add(checkBox);
        frame.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Applets? no. worst recommendation ever. Applets are hardly supported, since most major browsers have dropped support, and the others will shortly. What's the point in writing out-dated code that likely won't work when being tested by the teacher?